# Is there a way to check if a field exists for a Generic class?

Tags: java, generics, field

Is there a way to check if a field exists for a Generic class?

```
public class Person {
    public String name;
    public String street;
    ...
}

public class Car {
    public String name;
    ...
}

public abstract class Base<E> {
    ...
    public void doSomething(E entity) {
        String street = "";
        //Check if the generic entity has a "street" or not.
        // If a Person arrives: then the real street should appear
        // If a Car arrives: then an empty string would be needed
        logger.trace("Entity name: {}", street);
    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done with reflection, but I really think you should reconsider your design. Maybe you can do something based around interfaces?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no other way than using reflection. Should be something like this (not tested):

```
try {
   Field field = entity.getClass().getField("street");
   if (field.getType().equals(String.class) {
      street = (String) field.get(entity);
   }
} catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
  /* ignore */
}
```

If you have control over the type hierarchy, you could make an interface like `HasStreet` with a `getStreet()` method, and let your entities with streets implement it. That would be much cleaner: Just check if that interface is implemented, then cast and call the method.

Answer (score 1):

If you can reduce the different options for E, then you could just check the class with `instanceof`:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {
    public string name;
}

public class Person extends AbstractEntity {
    public String street;
    ...
}

public class Car extends AbstractEntity {

    ...
}

public abstract class Base<E extends AbstractEntity> {
    ...
    public void doSomething(E entity) {
        String street = "";
        //Check if the generic entity has a "street" or not.
        // If a Person arrives: then the real street should appear
        // If a Car arrives: then an empty string would be needed
        if (entity instanceof Person) {
            Person p= (Person) entity;
            street=p.street;
        } else  if (entity instanceof Car) {
            //...
        }
        logger.trace("Entity name: {}", street);
    }

}
```

If this is not the case, then you'll have to use reflexion:

```
try {
   Field field = entity.getClass().getField("street");
   street = (String) field.get(entity);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
  //This entity has no street field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't possibly access the local variables defined inside a class method. the compiler does not preserve the names.

If the attributes/fields are defined as the class level attributes, then you could access them the way @Landei mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to check if the field exist :

```
public void doSomething(E entity) {
    String street = "";
    Class<?> entityClass = entity.getClass();
    // getDeclaredField would allow to see non-public members
    Field streetField = entityClass.getField("street");
    // you should check the type of the filed here !
    logger.trace("Entity name: {}", streetField.get());
}
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html for more details.

Yet, the use of generics with reflection looks like a smell to me and I would advise to reconsider your design to make sure there is no other way!